# Find the last data in a table with conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[image: Excel Problem - please open this attachment file]

I want to get the latest END BALANCE of customer, when the STATUS is success. Picture of the table and result wanted is attached above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your data is sorted descending by column A, use in cell H4:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($E$2:$E$17,MATCH(1,(($C$2:$C$17="success")*($B$2:$B$17=$G4)),0)),"error")
```

This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>Shift</kbd> - <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Copy down.

Comment: I have tried it but the result is "error" for all customer.

Comment: Sorry, it works very well. Thanks for your help! :D

Comment: I tried to add one more condition, that is the END BALANCE (E2:E17) should be >10,000, but failed. =IFERROR(INDEX($E$2:$E$17,MATCH(1,(($C$2:$C$17="success")*($B$2:$B$17=$G4)*($E$2:$E$17>10000)),0)),"error"). Please help, thanks.

Comment: That formula works fine for me, too. Remember to use Ctrl-Shift-Enter to confirm it, not just Enter. Also, please next time don't post a photo of your screen. I've had to type your data twice now in order to check my formula. Please copy the cells and paste into your question. Also, your original question has been answered, so please mark the answer as described in the [Tour](http://superuser.com/tour)

Comment: Looking closer at your formula, there seems to be an invisible character (ascii code 63) after the $E$2 that you added. Try this: `=IFERROR(INDEX($E$2:$E$17,MATCH(1,(($C$2:$C$17="success")*($B$2:$B$17=$G4)*($E$2:$E$17>10000)),0)),"error")`

Comment: Thanks, it works fantastic! I will copy paste my data next time.